# Why doesn't $\sqrt {x^3} = x \sqrt {x}$

Tags: radicals

According to the law of radicals:

$$
\sqrt {an} = \sqrt a \cdot \sqrt n
$$

Wouldn't it make sense that: $\sqrt {x^3}= \sqrt {x^2} \cdot \sqrt x = x \sqrt x$

Obviously this doesn't work if you plug in values and compare, but this makes logical sense?

Comment: . . . But it does work for plugging in values.

Comment: Assuming you're plugging in negative values and that's where you're getting issues, then it's because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, not $\sqrt{x^2}=x$.

Comment: What value are you using? It works for positive values $x$

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ only works for $a, b \ge 0$, and so does $\sqrt{a^2} = a$. So yes, if $a \ge 0$, we have $\sqrt{a^3} = a \sqrt{a}$. And otherwise, if $a < 0$, then the square root is complex.

Comment: As everybody said before, the only problem is for negative real numbers, because then, neither the left or the right side make sense since you would have the square root of a negative numbers. If you were working in the complex field, this makes complete sense.

Comment: This is context-dependent. Would you care to give us some, so we can answer you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is mostly correct, except that it should read 
$$\sqrt {x^3}= \sqrt {x^2} \cdot \sqrt x = \color{red}{|x| \sqrt x}$$

Comment: And in the context of real numbers, the various expressions only make sense for $x\ge0,$ so....